# How to write AND condition in Numbers

Tags: macos, numbers

I have a dataset where I want to write a `COUNTIF`statement in Numbers (Mavericks). Specifically I want to count if a number is between 16 and 30.

So far I have tried: `COUNTIF(test-array, ">15 AND >= 30")` with no luck.

Reading from the documentation:

> condition: An expression that results in a boolean value of TRUE or FALSE. A condition can contain anything as long as the result from comparing it to a value in test-values can be expressed as TRUE or FALSE.

But I cannot find the correct logical and operator for the condition (tried `&&`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `COUNTIFS` instead of `COUNTIF`, using the same range for each test-array/condition pair.

`=COUNTIFS(test-array,">=16",test-array,"<=30")`

In the following example, the formula in A8 is `=COUNTIFS(A1:A6,">=16",A1:A6,"<=30")`

```
      A     B     C     D     E
1    10
2    15
3    20
4    25
5    30
6    35
7    
8     3
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. just a note: I got a syntax error when I used `,` as a sperator for the parameters of `countifs` but `;` seems to work fine. `=COUNTIFS(B2:B38;">15";B2:B38;"<=30")`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind a separate column/table for this, you can check if each cell is between 16 and 31 like this:

[image]

Table 2, A1:

```
IF(x::A1>15,IF(x::A1<31,TRUE,FALSE))
```

Table 2, A9:

```
COUNTIF(A,"=TRUE")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But in my case I actually do mind an extra column.